# IE browser "An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions " after windows upgrade

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

We are facing a wired issue. We did a windows upgrade on our application server and after the upgrade application is not loading in IE browser. We are getting blank page. In Google chrome everything looks fine.

I was checking if some IE setting is required but the interesting part for me is we have deployed the application on our production server and upgraded the server. The application is available on internet and if I am trying to access on my local machine then also the same issue so definitely it is not the IE setting.

Can someone help and let me know what may be the reason for this.